# Is there a way to open specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making a launcher app for nougat and above versions and I want user to land directly on (Settings-> Apps and Notifications -> Default apps -> Launcher List page) which is actually a fragment.

Android has provided ACTION_HOME_SETTINGS intent for opening launcher settings activity which only get user to (Settings-> Apps and Notifications -> Default apps).

So I want to know if we can open a specific fragment with known path by any means.

I don't know any way yet for opening a fragment through my activity.

Comment: What do you mean by accessing specific parts?

Comment: No, the main part of the android app is `Activity`. You may open a fragment directly once you have opened the at least one Activity per app.

Comment: To complete what @StavroXhardha said, load an Activity, in there you will be able to load Fragments as you like by doing transactions (cf. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments )

Comment: You might be loading the fragment from the activity correct? you can send an intent to this said activity with putExtra's and check the same in onNewIntent callback of the activity and load the fragment you need.